# How to create a list using Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I was wondering can someone help me here? I am new to javascript and jQuery and I am looking to create a mobile app where the user can create a list.

I am not looking for code to be given to me as I want to do it myself but I am looking for some guidance. I know for the items to store in a list I should create an array (an empty one), once the array is created should I create a linked list or a queue for the items?

If so can someone show me the pseudo code for it? Basically I am looking to do is create a list by entering in an item and once add item is selected it will show up in a list.

Any feedback will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can just create the list in the actual UI and then when you want to send it to a server, you fetch it from the DOM, put it in the right data format for sending to your server and send it via Ajax.  You don't need to maintain the list in a javascript data structure in parallel to what is showing in the UI.  More specific advice along this path would need to know what kind of UI you want.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to create an array of items: ["A", "list", "of", "items", "to", "add", "to", "the", "dom"]
- You need to iterate through each item in the array and inject the contents into the document with some javascript or jQuery. You can use the .forEach method of an array object, which passes each item in the array into a function.
- You can take that item that forEach passes and use one of jQuery's functions to add it to the DOM, such as .append().
- You can use a construct like $('UL') or $(".target") to find the DOM node you want to append the content to.

You may want to follow a tutorial for this. If you google something like 'Javascript Todo list tutorial' you'll find lots of options.